# Many-to-many relationship in SSAS Tabular project

Tags: many-to-many, ssas

I'm trying to set up a many-to-many relationship in SSAS Tabular.

I've got the following in my tabular project (sales, customers, customer emails):

[image]

A sale is tied to a customer. A customer can have multiple emails.

How would I create a list of all emails that fit the current filter of a pivot table?

For example, I could create a pivot table shows "accounts with margin < 20%", and want a list of all emails associated with those accounts.

Sample, starting with the following sales data:

```
customer #  | revenue
1234        | 100
6789        | 50
```

I would expect to see something like (depending on the exact pivot table settings)

```
1234      
  one@sample.com    | 100
  two@sample.com    | 100
6789      
  three@sample.com  | 50
```

(`one@sample.com` and `two@sample.com` are both tied to the same account)

Instead I get:

```
  1234
    one@sample.com    | 100
    two@sample.com    | 100
    three@sample.com  | 100
  5678
    one@sample.com    | 50
    two@sample.com    | 50
    three@sample.com  | 50
```

Comment: Hi did you figure this out?  I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @Lereveme I was never able to. The part that needed to do this is part of a scheduled job, so I was able to solve it in code at a different stage (that is, generate list A using SSAS and then do a join in C# / SQL to get list B). I still don't know how to set it up if you want to actually have a pivot table to show you that :-\

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would solve your problem but I solved my problem by creating a bridge relationship between the two many to many tables.  I couldn't find the exact article that I used but this one looks like it explains it:

http://brentgreenwood.blogspot.com/2011/12/case-for-bridge-tables.html

In your cube designer when you go to Dimension Usage one of the options is a "Many-to-Many".  The connecting "bridge" table should just have the identities of the two connecting dimension and fact table.  I know I didn't explain anything specific to your problem but perhaps this might help you get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-may relationship is not supported in SQL Server 2012 and 2014. SQL Server 2016 will contain this missing feature.
The simple work around to solve this issue is to place all related tables in filter. This shortcut worked in my environment. Example is given below for your reference.
Measure1:=calculate(sum[sales],'Customer','Emails')

Do let me know after try.