# Many to Many relationship in SSAS Tabular model

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

[Many o many relation in ssas tabular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Sx8.png)

Hi ,
      I have Accounts and Customers from an account should be related with multiple customers and customer also related with multiple Accounts .For these relation, I have attached screen shot what i have  designed in ssas tabular model.which is not working properly.

kindly advice me how to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Praveenkumar.k

Comment: Far more detail needed.  How is it not working properly?  What results are you getting?  What results should you be getting?  Please edit the question.

Comment: It's look like Cross apply, Every account is assigning every customer with same value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660509/many-to-many-relationship-in-ssas-tabular-project

Comment: You haven't explained how it doesn't work properly, but what I did was built a bridging table so that all realtionships were one to many, then followed this to make the outside table filter properly: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/optimize-many-to-many-calculation-in-dax-with-summarize-and-cross-table-filtering/

Answer (score 0):

just double-click on customer-account relationship and choose Bi-directional for filter direction.
this feature works with SSAS 2016 and SSDT2015.

For more information about this feature take a look:
[Bi-directional cross filters for tabular models in SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/mt591991.aspx)